# Sending messages to a particular room from a particular namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, chat

So, all my users are connected to a namespace called `rt`. How do I send a message to a particular room, let's say `roomA` for all the users inside this namespace and joined to `roomA` ?

```
namspace.on('connection',(socket) => {

   socket.on('new message',(data) => {
       // Send message to all users connected to roomA
   });

   socket.on('connect-room',(room) => {
      // room = 'roomA'
      socket.join(room).emit('room-join',{roomName : room});
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

pleas read here about the rooms and namespaces in socketio

```
 var nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');
 nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('someone connected'):
 });
nsp.to('some room').emit('hi', 'everyone!');
```